# Does a redis scan with a prefix match pattern scan all keys in database?

Tags: redis, redis-3.2

Let's say I have a redis instance with a million keys. The keys contain a team ID and a person ID and the values have some info about that team-person association.  Example keys:

```
team:1:person:123
team:2:person:234
team:2:person:345
...
```

I could use a `scan` with a pattern to get all the people on a given team. For example, `scan 0 match "team:123:person:*"`, would start getting everyone on team 123.

It sounds like this is *not* an efficient way to iterate over people in a team, because scan is O(N) where N is the number of keys in the *database*. But I want to confirm - is that the case?

A database with a tree index might only need to scan a small section of the tree, with keys with that prefix.

If it does scan everything, then I guess if I want to iterate quickly over people in a team, I need to store the set of person IDs under a team ID. Something like:

```
sset team:2:people 234 345 ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I want to confirm - is that the case?

Confirmed, that is indeed the case.

> store the set of person IDs under a team ID

That's exactly what you should. Mind, however, that once that Set grows too large doing [`SMEMBERS`](https://redis.io/commands/smembers) could be an expensive operation (hence impending the overall performance). If that indeed becomes an issue, use [`SSCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/sscan) to retrieve it leisurely-like instead.